# Display media volume in the status bar

Tags: cyanogenmod, audio, volume-control, notification-bar

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII running CM9.

Currently I have an app that displays my media volume by using a persistent notification.

However I have 2 problems with this.

1. Since media volume is a system thing, I feel that it shouldn't belong on the left hand side of the status bar.
2. This takes up a notification slot when I pull down the notification bar.

Is there a way that I can display the media volume on the right hand side in the status bar next to the battery level, clock, reception meter, etc?

Comment: For this, you'll have to modify/replace stock status bar...

Comment: As far as I know there's currently no way to add functionality like that without changing the source code of the stock status bar, your best bet may be a custom Status bar like Omega(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1825283) or Super(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1265106)

Answer (score -3):

You can install a widget known as Volume Ace. It gives access to all the volume levels in the system. You get 1X1  menu sizes as you prefer.

Comment: Please read the question. It clearly states right in the status bar. Not a widget or shortcut to volume settings.