# Show volume indicator on notification bar (just like WiFi/battery)

Tags: notification-bar, volume-control

I want to be able to see the volume level of my phone as a scalable icon that behaves just like WiFi and battery. If the volume is on full, it shows up completely white, empty shows up gray, etc.

Is there a default setting that I can't access (going into Volume on my phone's Settings causes Settings to crash), and is this even possible with an app?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/is-there-a-way-to-display-the-media-volume-in-the-status-bar?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the answer is a **no.**

Since changing the color of notification bar means modifying the system it can't be done by a normal application. Best you can do is an icon that can be added to the notification bar.

But there is a way if you are rooted.
[Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)  is a great app that lets users modify every single action executed at system level. You can use [Status Bar Volume](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.greatbytes.statusbarvolume) for what you want to have.

*Thanks to [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) for finding and sharing the name and link of the module and letting me using it in my answer*